# Error while deploying Laravel app on google cloud

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine

I get an error while deploying my laravel project on google cloud app engine.

This is the error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [7] The user "service-account-email" must have permission to read the image at us.gcr.io/"my project name"/appengine/default.20170907t141350:latest

I have also created service account and also give editor's role, even tried to repair using

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps/repair

and gave permission to create instances.

But I still keep getting this error

Anyone help me please?

Thanks